# Can't update mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

When putting an `anaylzer` into mapping using `PUT /job/_mapping/doc/` but get conflicts.
But there isn't a `anaylzer` in mappings.

```
PUT /job/_mapping/doc/
{
    "properties":{
        "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer":"ik_smart",
            "search_analyzer":"ik_smart"
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [title] has different [analyzer]]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:\n[mapper [title] has different [analyzer]]"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

```
                    "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "fielddata": true
                    },
```

The output config is like this.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["<Elasticsearch Hosts>"]
    user => "<user>"
    password => "<password>"
    index => "<table>"
    document_id => "%{<MySQL_PRIMARY_KEY>}"
  }
}
```

Comment: [Edit] those details into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant update mapping in `elasticsearch`, you can add mapping but not update mapping. Elasticsearch use mapping at the indexation time, that s why you cant update mapping of an existing field. Analyzer is part of the mapping, in fact if you don't specify one es a default one, analyzer tell elastic how to index the documents.

1. create a new index with your new mappings (include analyzer)
2. reindex your documents from your existing index to the new one (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html)

Comment: In fact, I sync data from mysql with Logstash, if reindex the documents when newer data comes, will index or anaylzer work well？

Comment: Do you use update (mutate) in logstash or you only add new documents?

Comment: I put my output config at question detail.

Comment: Well https://sematext.com/blog/recipe-reindexing-elasticsearch-documents-with-logstash/ will explain you exaclty what you have to do (tell us if you have question). It s should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Mapping:

Once a document is indexed to an index i.e. the mapping is generated under a given type as like in our case Mapping of `EmployeeCode`, `EmployeeName` & `isDevelopers`' is generated under type "`customtype`", we cannot modify it afterwards. In case if we want to modify it, we need to delete the index first and then apply the modified mapping manually and then re-index the data. But If you want to add an a new property under a given type, then it is feasible. For example, our document attached our index "inkashyap-1002" under type "customtype" is as follows:

```
{
  "inkashyap-1002": {
    "mappings": {
      "customtype": {
        "properties": {
          "EmployeeCode": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "isDeveloper": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "EmployeeName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

now let's add another property "Grade" :

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/inkashyap-1002(IndexName)/customtype(TypeName)/2 — d '{
 "EmployeeName": "Vaibhav Kashyap",
 "EmployeeCode": 13629,
 "isDeveloper": true,
 "Grade": 5
}'
```

Now hit the GET mapping API. In the results, you can see there is another field added called "Grade".

Common Error:

In the index "inkashyap-1002", so far we have indexed 2 documents. Both the documents had the same type for the field "EmployeeCode" and the type was "Long". Now let us try to index a document like below:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/inkashyap-1002/customtype/3 -d '{
"EmployeeName": "Vaibhav Kashyap",
 "EmployeeCode": "onethreesixtwonine",
 "isDeveloper": true,
 "Grade": 5
}'
```

Note that here the "EmployeeCode" is given in string type, which indicates that it is a string field. The response to the above request will be like below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failedtoparse[
          EmployeeCode
        ]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failedtoparse[
      EmployeeCode
    ]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "number_format_exception",
      "reason": "Forinputstring: \"onethreesixtwonine\""
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

In the above response, we can see the error "mapper_parsing_exception" on the field "EmployeeCode". This indicates that the expected field here was of another type and not string. In such cases re-index the document with the appropriate type

Comment: @Chetan Joshi, I really don't think any editing was required for this answer. I really welcome your activeness being a moderator. But being a developer we would appreciate more if you bring in changes making a difference and more accuracy, not just the FONT changes pal because I wasn't referring to code where you specifically converted that piece into code.